# cannot get field object with getByInternalNameOrTitle even though it shows up in enumeration using CSOM/JSOM

Tags: 2010, list, csom, column, jsom

I am using CSOM/JSON to get field data for a list. If I enumerate the list fields I get the field data/object. But if I look for one using `getByInternalNameOrTitle` I get the error "`The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.`".

The code below prints all the fields in that first `console.log` but that second one results in an error. What gives?

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function()
{
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Meeting Agenda Items");
    this.listFields = list.get_fields();
    clientContext.load(this.listFields);


    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, listFieldsLoaded), Function.createDelegate(this, function(){alert("error 1");}));
}, "sp.js");

function listFieldsLoaded()
{
    // if i enumerate the list fields this works fine
    var fieldEnumerator = listFields.getEnumerator();
    while(fieldEnumerator.moveNext())
    {
        var thisField = fieldEnumerator.get_current();
        console.log(thisField.get_internalName());
    }

    // but if i try to get it by an internal name
    // then it does not
    var thisField = listFields.getByInternalNameOrTitle("Title");
    console.log(thisField.get_internalName());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the thisField variable into the context.

```
var thisField;

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function()
{
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Meeting Agenda Items");
    this.listFields = list.get_fields();
    clientContext.load(this.listFields);
    thisField = listFields.getByInternalNameOrTitle("Title");

    clientContext.load(thisField);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, listFieldsLoaded), Function.createDelegate(this, function(){alert("error 1");}));
}, "sp.js");

function listFieldsLoaded()
{
    // if i enumerate the list fields this works fine
    var fieldEnumerator = listFields.getEnumerator();
    while(fieldEnumerator.moveNext())
    {
        var thisField = fieldEnumerator.get_current();
        console.log(thisField.get_internalName());
    }


    console.log(thisField.get_internalName());
}
```

This will return the field name. (you can move the variable somewhere and pass it as a parameter) I was just doing this quickly.

Comment: I don't understand why I have to load it into context when it works fine through `getEnumerator` without explicitly loading each field into the context?

Comment: I wish I had an answer to that. I can only say that the Client context seems to only load pieces at a time, any time that the error thrown says something about being explicitly called it usually means it has to be loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

why not set it before you add it to the context:

single field into the context:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function()
{
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Meeting Agenda Items");
    this.listFields = list.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Title");
    clientContext.load(this.listFields);


    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, listFieldsLoaded), Function.createDelegate(this, function(){alert("error 1");}));
}, "sp.js");

function listFieldsLoaded()
{
    console.log(listFields.get_internalName());
}
```

or

all fields into the context:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function()
{
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Meeting Agenda Items");
    this.listFields = list.get_fields();
    clientContext.load(this.listFields);


    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.listFieldsLoaded), Function.createDelegate(this, function(){alert("error 1");}));
}, "sp.js");

function listFieldsLoaded()
{
    console.log(listFields.get_fields().getByInternalNameOrTitle("Title").get_internalName());
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why I have to load it into context when it works fine through `getEnumerator` without explicitly loading each field into the context?

Comment: updated answer. loads all fields into the context and get internal name within success method

Comment: That won't work. That is the exact same thing I tried in my example question and it gives an error.

Comment: sorry updated my answer

Comment: I think the issue is your returning a collection and cant use the getByInternalNameOrTitle directly. I understand what your trying to do

Comment: the first method that I showed you is the correct method. otherwise you need to loop through. The second method might work